# Are my answers corect for the following 2 sets questions?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I'm working on my HW and I am needing help.

1. $ \{3\} $ is a subset of P(Q) (meaning the power set of rational numbers)
2. $\{\{3\}\}$ is a subset P(Q).

For 1 I am just not too sure because I feel like it's true but I'm not sure how to explain myself.
for 2 I have that this is true because it can be rewritten as 3 is an element of Q which is true. 3 is a rational number. 
Thank you!

Comment: Be very careful with the definitions... actually the answer you have for (2) is the correct answer for (1)!

Comment: @MeesdeVries so 1 and 2 are both true? I understand how 2 is correct but how is 1 true?

Comment: Ah, my bad, I misread your question. Please forget what I said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any set, the collection of all its subsets is called the power set. This means that for any $A$, $\mathcal{P}(A)$ has sets for elements - strange, huh?

That being said, $\{ \{ 3 \} \} \subset \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Q}) $ but $\{ 3 \} \not \subset \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Q})$!

**Expanded explanation**: Let's consider the set $A = \{ 1, 2, 3 \}. $ Then $\mathcal{P}(A) = \{ \emptyset, \{ 1 \}, \{ 2 \}, \{ 3 \}, \{ 1, 2 \}, \{ 1, 3 \}, \{ 2, 3 \}, \{ 1, 2, 3 \} \}$. All the elements of this power set are sets themselves. When we have $\{ \text{foo} \}$ this means that foo is an element, while $\{ \{ \text{foo} \} \}$ is the set containing the set containing foo.

Better example: What's the difference between $\emptyset$ and $\{ \emptyset \}$? One is a set containing nothing, the other is a set containing a set with no elements - like an empty box and a box with an empty box in it.

Comment: Hmm...I'm not sure I understand how the part after but it not true. This means number one is false is what you are saying. But could you please maybe explain it a bit more? I also see this implies 2 is true.

Comment: See my edited post.

Comment: Ah I get is. {3} doesn't work because it's not necessarily a subset it's an element. So then {3} is a subset of P(Q) is false.